# ServiceBroker communication between databases without TRUSTWORTHY ON

Tags: sql-server, service-broker

I have 2 databases within single SqlServer instance.
I need to send a message from one database to another using ServiceBroker services.
How can it be done without setting TRUSTWORTHY to "ON" on the database, because in my case this is not the option due to security risks?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You must set up dialog security, with certificates, see [Certificates for Dialog Security](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms166117%28v=sql.105%29.aspx):

- create DB master keys on both DBs involved
- create and export a certificate for the initiator service owner (likely dbo)

  `USE <initiatordb>;`
   `CREATE CERTIFICATE [<initiatorservicename>] AUTHORIZATION [<initiatorserviceowner>] WITH SUBJECT = '<initiatorservicename>';`
   `BACKUP CERTIFICATE [<initiatorservicename>] TO FILE = 'c:\temp\<initiatorservicename>.cer'`;
- do the same, for target service:

  `USE <targetdb>;`
   `CREATE CERTIFICATE [<targetservicename>] AUTHORIZATION [<targetserviceowner>] WITH SUBJECT = '<targetservicename>';`
   `BACKUP CERTIFICATE [<targetservicename>] TO FILE = 'c:\temp\<targetservicename>.cer'`;
- import the initiator service owner's cert in the target DB, create a proxy user for it and grant SEND permission:

  `USE <targetdb>;`
    `CREATE USER [<initiatorserviceproxyuser>] WITHOUT LOGIN;`
    `CREATE CERTIFICATE [<initiatorservicename>] AUTHORIZATION [<initiatorserviceproxyuser>] FROM FILE='c:\temp\<initiatorservicename>.cer'`
    `GRANT SEND ON SERVICE::[<targetservicename>] TO [<initiatorserviceproxyuser>];`
- import the target service owners' certificate in initiator DB, create a proxy user for it and map the remote service binding:

  `USE <initiatordb>;`
    `CREATE USER [<targetserviceproxyuser>] WITHOUT LOGIN;`
    `CREATE CERTIFICATE [<targetservicename>] AUTHORIZATION [<targetserviceproxyuser>] FROM FILE='c:\temp\<targetservicename>.cer'`
    `CREATE REMOTE SERVICE BINDING [<targetservicename>] WITH SERVICE_NAME = '<targetservicename>', USER =  [<targetserviceproxyuser>];`

I typed all this from memory, I hope I got the syntax right.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It needed a master key, so I added it with this statement: CREATE MASTER KEY ENCRYPTION BY PASSWORD ='PASSWORD' GO ALTER MASTER KEY ADD ENCRYPTION BY SERVICE MASTER KEY. But now I'm getting the following error: 'The private key for the security certificate bound to the database principal (ID 1) is password protected. 
Password protected private keys are not supported for use with secure dialogs.'

Comment: It means you created the certificate with password protection, not with master key protection as in my example. Remove the `ENCRYPTION  BY PASSWORD ... ` clause from the certificate creation.

Comment: Now set a calendar reminder to replace the certificates when they expire (one year from now)